# Windows Subsystem for Linux gedit error

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, gedit, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) with VcXsrv windows manager (GUI) for Linux under Windows with Xfce4 from `Xubuntu-Desktop` and am getting this error message every time I start `gedit`:

```
** (gedit:143): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-qyusGiP2Dq: Connection refused
```

Additionally the error seems to cause a "lag" before `gedit` runs (which it does OK, except rare time under `sudo -h` frying things) but the error message is disconcerting as is the perceived "lag".

Answer (score 5):

Similar to this thread on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230238/starting-x-applications-from-the-terminal-and-the-warnings-that-follow) the error is caused by "accessability warning" which is known as a bug.

The solution is to edit your `~/.bashrc` file and put in the following line(s) (the comments (beginning with `#`) are optional):

```
# gedit error: ** (gedit:143): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility
# bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-qyusGiP2Dq: Connection refused
# As per: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230238/starting-x-applications-from-the-terminal-and-the-warnings-that-follow
# This also speeds up gedit load time
export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
```

The error message will go away and `gedit` will appear to load faster (at least on an Samsung Pro 960 bench-marked at 2.2 GBps on Linux and 3.4 GBps on Windows 10).

Comment: This also works for my starting emacs in Ubuntu/WSL. Thanks!